# Mat Slider value not getting updated while sliding

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Mat slider value is not sync updated while sliding.

```
<mat-slider [(ngModel)]="myValue" step="1" min="0" max="100" ></mat-slider>
{{myValue}}
```

It just got updated only after release slider thumb.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the javascript input event:

```
<mat-slider [(ngModel)]="myValue" (input)="myValue = $event.value"></mat-slider>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to bind the `input` output (weird name selection) to a handler, see [the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api#MatSlider). If you want to keep track of the slider value you could to the following:

```
<mat-slider (change)="updateSliderValue($event)" (input)="updateSliderValue($event)
 [(ngModel)]="myValue" 
 step="1" min="0" max="100" ></mat-slider>
{{ slideValue$ | async }}


import {MatSliderChange} from '@angular/material';
// Using rxjs@6.x
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs'
private slideSubject = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
readonly slideValue$ = this.slideSubject.asObservable();

updateSliderValue(event: MatSliderChange){
    slideSubject.next(event.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using reactive forms with FormControl you can directly call `setValue` on the form control like this:

```
(input)="form.controls['direction'].setValue($event.value)"
```

Comment: It works, but sometimes the slider stops and doesn't continue to slide, maybe it's busy making all the previous changes that are waiting for an input event

Comment: I moved the code to the function and now it works great!! `(input)="setValue($event)"`.    `setValue(event:any){form.controls['direction'].setValue(event.value)}`

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 17 using Angular Material it seems to now be `$event.target.valueAsNumber` instead of `event.value`

```html
<mat-slider [(ngModel)]="myValue" (input)="myValue = $event.target.valueAsNumber"></mat-slider>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).